# Как различить время суток?

Tags: лексика

11 часов утра или дня? 4 часа вечера или дня? 4 часа утра или ночи? Есть ли какие-то точные правила на этот счет?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В русском языке чёткой границы нет. Примерное разделение выглядит так:

1. Утро от 4-5 часов до 11-12.
2. День от 11-12 часов до 15-16.
3. Вечер от 15-16 часов до 23-24.
4. Ночь от 23-24 часов до 4-5.

Это всё очень примерно и крайне субъективно. Условно, утро - это время когда люди уже просыпаются, но ещё не пообедали, день - от обеда до конца работы, вечер - от окончания работы до сна, ночь - время сна. График у людей разный и значения поэтому тоже разные.

Ещё можно добавить, что так как утро и вечер у нас получаются длиннее дня и ночи, то вполне можно выделить *раннее утро* (до рассвета) и *поздний вечер* (после заката солнца).

Answer (score 7):

[Когда заканчивается утро и начинается день?](http://strana-sovetov.com/miscellaneous/4013-times-of-day.html)

В большинстве европейских стран принято единое разделение суток. Согласно этому разделению сутки делятся на четыре равных промежутка по шесть часов каждый. Получается, что времена суток распределяются следующим образом:

- с 0 до 6 часов — ночь
- с 6 до 12 часов — утро
- с 12 до 18 часов — день
- с 18 до 24 часов — вечер

Comment: "Большинство европейских стран" слабо соотносятся с темой "Русский язык". Просто прознесите "5 часов ночи" и вы поймете, что ваш ответ некорректен.

Answer (score 6):

Не знаю существуют ли правила на этот счет, но определенно в разговорной речи употребляется

с 11 до 3 часов ночь (соответственно, говорят: 3:30 ночи, но полчетвертого утра)

с 4 до 11 часов утро (соответственно, говорят: 11:30 утра, но полдвенадцатого дня)

с 12 до 4 часов день (соответственно, говорят: 4:30 дня, но полпятого вечера)

с 5 до 10 часов вечер (соответственно, говорят: 10:30 вечера, но пол-одиннадцатого ночи)

По корпоративным правилам некоторых компаний запрещено здороваться с клиентами обозначая утро, день, вечер, и тем более ночь. Принято здороваться "Добрый день" на протяжении всего рабочего дня (примерно с 9 утра до 6 вечера). Это делается для того, чтобы клиент понимал, что рабочий день в компании начался и продолжается. То есть под словом "день" подразумевается не время суток, а рабочий день. Согласитесь, что клиент может понять "Доброе утро" как, у нас еще утро и мы только проснулись, или "Добрый вечер - уже вечер и нам пора домой.

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке неявно предполагается такое же деление, что и в европейских. 
Во всяком случае до 12:00 принято желать "доброго утра", до 18:00 - дня, после - вечера. 
Именно так и стоит, имхо, говорит в отношении времени суток. Вот с ночью некоторые проблемы. "Доброй ночи" означает не совсем то же, что "утра" или "вечера", а начиная с четырех часов говорят "утра". Но это уже наблюдение, не догма. Так что расхождения наблюдаются только на протяжении трех утренних часов.

> 11 часов утра или дня? 4 часа вечера или дня? 4 часа утра или ночи?

Я бы сказал 11 утра, 4 часа (дня), 4 утра. Не настаиваю.
Насчет 4 дня могут быть небольшие колебания. Если "только четыре" - то дня. Если "уже" - то вечера. 
А вообще с четырьмя и пятью часами пополудни обычно ни "дня", ни "вечера" не употребляется

Comment: Никогда не слышал *5 часов дня*, а с вечером "5 часов" доводилось видеть довольно часто.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ прост: в больших компаниях стандарт общения с клиентом. Приветствовать клиента "здравствуйте", либо с 4 утра до 12 - "доброе утро", с 12 до 18 - "добрый день", с 18 до 22 - "добрый вечер" и с 22 до 4 - "добрый ночи". Запомните!

Comment: Вы наверно знаете стандарты общения **всех** больших компаний России, раз позволяете себе столь менторский тон. Правда даже в этом случае это не более чем внутренний стандарт, к литературной норме имеющий лишь опосредованное отношение.

Comment: Вопрос не о приветствиях и не о клиентах.

Comment: Действительно. А мы-то голову ломали. Оказывается надо запоминать то, что делается в больших компаниях. А если не так, то компания маленькая. И они этого не знают. Потому что это секрет.  *Большой секрет для маленькой, для маленькой такой компании огромный такой секрет!*

Answer (score 0):

тут, похоже, два вопроса. Как воспринимается людьми это разделение по времени суток и как выразиться так, чтобы тебя поняли однозначно. Первое можно обсуждать, второе - надумано, поскольку сказать четыре утра и четыре ночи - это ясно что не вечера и не ночи, ошибки не будет.

А по поводе менталитета, то тут так. либо человек строго придерживается "английской" версии (как я), либо называет "ночью" период с 00:00 до 03:00 (дальше "утро" аж до 11:59), а "днем" - с 12:00 до 15:00 или 16:00, потому уже "вечер" до полуночи. Но это никому не мешает и представляет скорее чисто познавательный интерес.